# How to use C# string inside jQuery in Razor?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, string, razor

I am using razor view and jQuery. I would like to write value in the razor view into header of modal dialog. (view is opening inside bootstrap modal dialog)

With debugging I've found out that `string title` is filled with text. But, when modal opens, it is empty.

If I try the same code and write:

```
$(".modal-title").text("this is just for test");
```

everything is fine, text is inside modal dialog header.

Why it is not written from `string title`?

```
@model iCommCommon.DTO_CAORAM


@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/LayoutModal.cshtml";

    string title = "Details " + Model.cMEST_CDO2;
}


<script type="text/javascript">    
    $(".modal-title").text(@title);        
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to wrap the value coming from Razor in quotes so that the JS code interprets it as a string:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    $(".modal-title").text('@title');        
</script>
```

This is obviously assuming that your `<script>` tag is at the end of the `<body>`, otherwise you will also need to wrap the jQuery code in a document.ready event handler.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one :

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
   $(function(){
     $(".modal-title").text('@title');   
   });        
</script>
```

Comment: That is exactly the same as Rory McCrossan pointed out. Without the explanations.